# Adodb using php with PostgreSQL - ADODB ASSOC_CASE not working

Tags: php, adodb-php

Trying  below code

```
*require "./adodb.inc.php";
define('ADODB_ASSOC_CASE', ADODB_ASSOC_CASE_UPPER);
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
 
$db = ADONewConnection('postgres');
$db->connect($host, $user, $password, $database);*
```

able to connect to database but ADODB_ASSOC_CASE is setting to 2 as NATIVE instead of 1 i.e UPPER

is there any way to force set the value of ADODB_ASSOC_CASE to UPPER

Comment: This is it, per documentation https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:adodb_assoc_case. Are you saying you are not getting the recordset with fieldnames in uppercase ? Which version of ADOdb is this ?